# how to make a list of objects without losing reference

Tags: python, function, class

--------------------------------EDITED----------------------------------------

here is the whole code, sorry i forgot to add the @classmethod decorator

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Player(ABC):

    player_list = []

    @classmethod
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0
        Player.player_list.append(self)

    @abstractmethod
    def getname(self):
        pass


class generic(Player):
    def getname(self):
        return self.name


p1 = generic('bob')
p2 = generic('tim')

p1.name = 'steve'

for player in Player.player_list:
    print(player.name)
```

this doesn't return steve, tim
instead returns tim, tim

also

```
print(Player.player_list)
```

returns

```
[<class '__main__.generic'>, <class '__main__.generic'>]
```

Comment: [mcve] please. For instance `player.player_list.append(self)` should be `Player.player_list.append(self)`

Comment: Everything works for me as intended.
```>>> class Player:
...  l = []
...  def __init__(self, name):
...   self.name = name
...   Player.l.append(self)
...
>>>
>>> a = Player("a")
>>> a
<__main__.Player object at 0x000002B7AD22D4E0>
>>> Player.l[0]
<__main__.Player object at 0x000002B7AD22D4E0>```

Comment: "NameError: name 'player' is not defined" in your example. Pleas post correct code

Comment: It uses reference, so works fine, how could you get your results, strange.

Comment: @C.Yduqoli As he said the reference of the object remains same in the list as well.

Comment: it is strange, I just simplified this code from my original one since its too long, i guess ill go check again

Comment: Yes, current code works fine, you need to find your original code, and after simplelify it, please try it yourself to see if can still reproduce your issue.

Comment: I found the problem now, it was because of a @classmethod in the __init__ fuction, also edited the code I posted

Comment: @classmethod doesn't really make sense for init. This will just overwrite your name each time, because name is a class attribute and not an instance attribute.

Comment: @C.Yduqoli, so if I would add the name it should be in the child classes?

Comment: but what if I wanted all child classes to have names? isn't it better to just add them in the base class?

Comment: What's wrong with just removing @classmethod? What is it you actually want to do?

Comment: @C.Yduqoli I want all the child classes to run the __init__ method

Comment: now that I try it, removing it fixes the problem, guess I was just misusing/misunderstanding what classmethod is for, thanks @C.Yduqoli

Answer (score 0):

you should use iterator object called `player_list` in order to retrieve newly inserted data, via class object. you ain't get anything out of the empty list.  your operations are incorrect.
Please see below,

```
p1 = Player('bob')
print(p1)

for p in p1.player_list:
    print(p.name)
print(p1.player_list[0].name)
```

Output:-

```
<__main__.Player object at 0x10851c2b0>
bob
bob
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to give you some explanation why you get strange behavior if you use `classmethod` on `__init__` in case you are interested.

```
class Player:
    player_list = []

    @classmethod
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0
        Player.player_list.append(self)

    p1 = Player('bob')
    print("1: " + p1.name)
    p2 = Player('tim')
    print("2: " + p1.name)
    print("3: " + p2.name)
    p1.name = 'steve'
    print("4: " + p1.name)
    for player in Player.player_list:
        print("5: " + player.name)
```

The output will be:

```
1: bob
2: tim
3: tim
4: steve
5: tim
5: tim
```

For above code, when you do it, the `self` in `__init__` will no longer mean object of one class, you can `print(self)` to see it is `<class '__main__.Player'>`, not `<__main__.Player object at 0x7f3264820fd0>`, which means the self is class, not object. In fact, if we use `classmethod`, usually we will change `self` to `cls`.

So `self.name = name` not as you expected set value `bob` or `tim` to object attribute, it in fact just set to `Player.name`, this is a class attribute. One class just have one class attribute with the same name, so you can see when `p2 = Player('tim')` finish, both `p1` & `p2` have the name `tim`.

What happened for `p1.name = 'steve'`, here, `p1` is a object, this will add a `object attribute` with the name `name` to `p1 object`, so now `p1.name` no longer means `Player.name`, it really means the object attribute of p1. So `print("4: " + p1.name)` will give you `steve`.

Finally, what happened for below, why still `tim`?

```
for player in Player.player_list:
    print("5: " + player.name)
```

This is because `Player.player_list.append(self)` already add the `<class '__main__.Player'>` to `Player.player_list`, the `player` is class not object, so still show `tim`.